# GATE Exception ! Can not guess GATE home Please set it manually

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, text-mining, gate

I'm trying to call gate program from command prompt am using example from following code in this link:

http://gate.ac.uk/wiki/code-repository/src/sheffield/examples/StandAloneAnnie.java

Step 1 : I replaced StandAloneAnnie with a name "mario"

Step 2 : I added .jar and .zip files in classpath of my java program and a single document path in the argument.

Step 3 : complied it with no errors but with an exception , called the program in CMD prompt and I get following error !

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.....
Caused by: gate.until.GateRuntimeException: Cannot guess GATE Home. Please set manually

I tried both methods

Method 1 : using Gate.setGateHome(File) using following code before Gate.init()

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws GateException, IOException {
// initialise the GATE library
Out.prln("Initialising GATE...");
Gate.setGateHome(new File("E:/Gate/Installation/"));
Gate.setPluginsHome(new File("E:/Gate/Installation/plugins/"));
Gate.setSiteConfigFile(new File("E:/Gate/Installation/gate.xml"));
Gate.init();
Out.prln("...GATE initialised");
```

Method 2: using this in cmd -Dgate.home=path/to/gate/home

```
java -jar mario.jar -Dgate.home=E:\Gate\Installation
```

More Information :

I'm using Java 1.7.45
My gate is in E:\Gate\Installation folder.

In Java i get following exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: e
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:574)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:464)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:413)
    at mario.main(mario.java:98)
```

Am I doing something wrong in this. Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try Putting GATE_HOME in environment variable directing to the Gate Root directory, This might solve your problem.

Also look for the references If you have changed/renamed any variable.

My suggestion is that first you try to run with default names then change/update name as required